# dispatcher-servlet.xml and application-context.xml

Tags: java, spring

1. Why do we use dispatcher
   servlet.xml?
2. Is it something like web.xml?
3. Is application and dispatcher xmls
   different from each other, are there
   any similar things which both can
   do?
4. I have a value, now i need to send
   it to another class? can i do it via
   application-context.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Because people don't want one humongous application-context.xml, they split them up by application layer.
2. No, it's just a Spring application context file.
3. They do the same thing.
4. That's not what it's for, it's for defining what your spring-managed objects get injected with.

Answer (score 24):

In addition to Nathans' answer - the `dispatcher-servlet.xml` defines a *child context* of the base application context (define in `applicationContext.xml`)

Child contexts have access to all the beans defined in the parent context, but parents don't have access to beans in the child contexts.

Comment: This is key in understanding this. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

1. Dispatcher servlet.xml is just the convention followed by the Spring front controller for web MVC applications.  If you don't use Spring web MVC, you need not have a dispatcher-servlet.xml
2. web.xml is the configuration file required by a Java web app.  You must have a web.xml for a Java web app, but the Spring servlet.xml is only required if you use Spring web MVC.
3. The Spring servlet XML is just part of a Spring web application configuration.  You can put all your Spring configuration in the single XML file if you wish, but usually people have more than one.
4. Spring's bean factory creates objects and injects their dependencies.  Your code does the rest.  Define what "send it to another class" means to you.