# Spring @Value annotations don't work, returning null

Tags: java, spring, annotations, mule

I have the following class:

```
@Component
public class MyClass {

@Value("${main.url}") private String mainUrl;
```

the following XML context:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
  <context:component-scan base-package="mypackage"/>

  <context:property-placeholder file-encoding="UTF-8" location="classpath:/app.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
```

and prop file:

```
main.url=veryniceurl.com
```

Injection doesn't work, it is always null.
I read a lot of similar examples and I thought that everything is ok but it isn't. Can anyone tell me if I forgot about something? I'm working with Mule ESB.

Comment: is `app.properties` in the root of your classpath? You should try with `ignore-unresolvable` set to `false` to see if Spring complains.

Answer (score 1):

[@Value doesn't seem to work with Mule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12493421/664054). Instead you need to wire it up through the Mule XML, where I assume you are loading your component as a Spring Bean:

```
<spring:bean id="MyClass" class="com.example.MyClass">
   <spring:property name="mainUrl" value="${main.url}"/>
</spring:bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give an id to your properties and use this syntax :

```
@Value("#{jetProperties['jetBean.name']}")

<!-- define the properties file to use -->
<util:properties id="jetProperties" location="classpath:/jet.properties" />
```

From http://chrislovecnm.com/2010/03/08/spring-3-java-based-configuration-with-value/

Comment: Thanks for your response but i tried that before and it doesnt works. I changed syntax and its null again...

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the context placeholder in the dispatcher-servlet.xml ? As per here, [Spring @Value annotation in @Controller class not evaluating to value inside properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890544/spring-value-annotation-in-controller-class-not-evaluating-to-value-inside-pro) they seem to have solved it by adding it there instead of the application context

Comment: I dont have dispatcher-servlet.xml file, u mean it is web.xml ? How to add <context:property-placeholder> there?

Comment: The dispatcher-servlet.xml is a child context of the applicationContext.xml (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549034/dispatcher-servlet-xml-and-application-context-xml) The dispatcher-servlet.xml (usually named as "dispatchername"-servlet) is the place where commonly are stored the controller and resolver configurations (such as viewResolver)